# Class of Matrixes in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ which have a nullspace of binary vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm working on a research topic and I was wondering if the class of matrices, which have a nullspace of binary vectors, is already well defined by some attributes other than their nullspace? A binary vector is a vector, which entries only consist of $0$ and $1$s. So for example, let $A \in M(n,m,\mathbb{R})$ be a Matrix from this class.
$$
Null(A) := \{ \alpha(x_1, \dots, x_n)| (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \{0,1\}^n and \,\alpha \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$

EDIT: I'm sorry, of course, it can also contain scaled versions of this vector

Comment: A null space is a vector space, so if some binary vector is in it, so is $1/2$ times that vector, as well, and the negative of that vector.  So a null space containing _only_ binary vectors cannot contain non-zero binary vectors (since $1/2$ and $-1$ are not bits).  That is, such a space is $0$ dimensional.

Comment: What sort of attributes are you looking for? A property for example is that the sum of a subset of the columns of your matrix is 0, but that's just a reinterpretation of the fact that a binary vector is in the nullspace.

Comment: @mathma I don't know right now, I was just wondering if there is already literature about it